# Getting error as "'query' is string; want dict" while executing cloud workflow in google cloud

Tags: google-bigquery, google-workflows

I followed this very useful article by Marton https://martonkodok.medium.com/automate-the-execution-of-bigquery-queries-with-cloud-workflows-9fffe0557dbb to automate the execution of big query using cloud workflow and also other article https://medium.com/codeshake/build-a-serverless-bigquery-ingestion-pipeline-using-cloud-workflows-f893f6b701ee.

I was able to create workflow with simple sql query. However, getting error as below while executing the procedure.

```
'query' is string; want dict
in step "InvokeProdcedure", routine "main", line: 9
{
  "message": "'query' is string; want dict",
  "tags": [
    "TypeError"
  ]
}
```

Below is a very simple code where I am calling a procedure.

```
# This is a sample workflow to test or replace with your source code.
#
# This workflow returns a list of Wikipedia articles related to a search term.
# The search term is retrieved from a Cloud Function that returns the current day of the week
# (in GMT), unless a search term is given as input (e.g. {"searchTerm": "Monday"}).
main:
    steps:
    - InvokeProdcedure:
        call: googleapis.bigquery.v2.jobs.query
        args:
            projectId: ${sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID")}
            query:  >
                  DECLARE source_dataset_name STRING DEFAULT NULL;
                  DECLARE source_table_name STRING DEFAULT NULL;
                  DECLARE destination_dataset_name STRING DEFAULT NULL;
                  DECLARE destination_table_name STRING DEFAULT NULL;
                  DECLARE recordstamp_column_name STRING DEFAULT NULL;
                  DECLARE flag_column_name STRING DEFAULT NULL;
                  DECLARE is_deleted_column_name STRING DEFAULT NULL;
                  DECLARE pk_colmun_name_list ARRAY<STRING> DEFAULT NULL;
                  CALL `project.dataset.procedure_name`(*Values passed for all variables above)
        result: queryResult
```

What is that I am doing wrong here. Is this not the right way to call procedure in cloud workflow?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this. There was syntax error.
body was missing in my code. Please see below google documentation.

[image]